# Hunting for mystery wardrobe fixings/bolts

Tags: joinery, furniture, cabinetry, fasteners, hardware-identification

I am looking for the bolt fixings for a large (mahogany/walnut?) wardrobe whose fixings were lost in delivery. However I am mystified as to what mechanism was used - looking for guidance on what clues the holes left may offer. It was from a house clear I believe so no way of going back to a previous owner. Searched everything I can think of to no avail.

Below gives an impression of the wardrobe - lovely finish so keen to find a way to put it back together. One of the two sets of doors and a side panel shown below.
[image: One of the two sets of doors and a side panel shown here]

Floor panels fix and support the side panels with a dowel + bolt fixing as shown here. The left hole has a threaded insert (temporarily removed)
[image: Floor to side panel fixing]

My challenge is what fixing allowed a bolt to be secured on the end not screwed into the threaded insert. Is this some type of unusual cam lock? There is a conical hole from which the other end of a bolt could be partially accessed but I am not aware of any cam style mechanism that works in this way. Access holes/cam nuts have straight sides - and being solid hardwood any fixing would have had to be strong.
[image: Conical hole, presumably allowing a bolt to be tightened/locked]
Any ideas on what mechanism might match here?
I’ve looked all over for markings that might indicate make and so narrow down search but nothing other than a stamped underlined 6 on each section.

All ideas much appreciated!
Jonny

Comment: Possibly something like these https://www.amazon.com/TUOREN-Cabinet-Furniture-Connecting-Pre-Inserted/dp/B07RFTZ1M2/ref=asc_df_B07RFTZ1M2/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=366402178286&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=389498749312167537&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9019782&hvtargid=pla-805787875368&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=79101501587&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=366402178286&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=389498749312167537&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9019782&hvtargid=pla-805787875368

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Wow that is some choice burr veneer there! After shooting whoever is responsible for losing the original fixings :-) the clues here don't give much to go on, so not too surprised you haven't had luck yet. But if someone is familiar with the system I'm sure they'll recognise it right away. The larger hole we're seeing here, can't be quite sure from the photos but it is conical right? My first thought was a countersink-shaped connector, but that doesn't seem like it makes sense because there doesn't appear to be any access to the other end of the bolt.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't get lucky here do post this on one of the busier woodworking forums with large, active memberships; there are actually only a handful of regulars here, along with a larger number of infrequent posters. I'm thinking the Reddit sub might be your best bet as although it's not the best for woodworking advice (in part because the signal/noise ratio can be too low) it's gotta have the largest standing membership of any woodworking forum there is, so might maximise your chances of someone who knows the answer seeing your photos.

Comment: Thanks both appreciate you taking the time. Yes Graphus, it’s this conical hole that’s the key. I‘ve searched all over for conical cam nuts or some sort of massive grub screw (albeit the latter wouldn’t pull the joint tight) but not found anything. Half a mind to drill it out and fix with the cylindrical cam fixings you get on beds (35x17mm seen here emflatpack.co.uk/products.php?id=4). I’ll try the bigger forums too, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: *"Half a mind to drill it out and fix with the cylindrical cam fixings you get on beds"* Isn't the 17mm depth a dealbreaker? Even if the material is a full 18mm thickness (rather than 18mm nominal) there's not really enough margin, plus you'd need to use an end mill rather than a Forstner bit.

Comment: Sorry, busy weekend. It might not matter as I could drill full thickness then, if needed to stabilise, add a plate of some sort on the underside. Need to check if it interferes with the plinths that fit top and bottom but patch work would be hidden. 
I still keep being drawn back to trying to solve the puzzle though… Just can’t believe there is a fixing of this type that can be that obscure!